# Velocity of mass colliding with another mass under the influence of gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation

> If two spherical objects of mass $m$ and mass $4m$ are in outer space with no other forces other than the gravitational attraction between them and they're separated by distance $d$, what velocity will the object of mass $m$ have when they collide? **The objects are not point masses; the one with $4m$ mass has $2r$ radius and the one with mass $m$ has radius $r$.**

What messed me up the most is, to me, the number of factors we have to take in when doing the calculation; both masses move, so we have to account for a gravitational field that acts over a shorter period of time yet that increases more rapidly; in addition, they aren't point masses so we have to account for the fact that when they collide their center of masses will be separated by distance 3r not 0.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: The fact that they have a finite size is what makes this easier (possible) to do. You know the gravitational potential energy as a function of distance; so you know the total kinetic energy when they are at a distance of 3r. Now the ratio of velocities is given by the inverse of their masses (conservation of momentum). That gives you two equations and you can solve for velocity.

Comment: @Floris Wow I can't believe it was that simple! Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you say, it would be a very difficult problem if we had to resort to using Newton's laws to calculate the forces and accelerations at every point along the trajectories. Thankfully, the universe has conservation laws which make this problem immensely easier. Try using the conservation of mechanical energy and the conservation of total momentum.